# Logarithm addition with different bases

Tags: logarithms

How to solve the following? $$\log_2{8}+ \log_3{27}$$
Please advise whether my method below is correct or not?
$$\begin{align*}\log_2{8}&=3 \\ \log_3{27}&=3 \end{align*}$$
Answer is: $3+3=6$.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Please learn how to use Math Jax

Comment: @ParclyTaxel How do you have a comment with $4$ characters?

Comment: @idk By using filler MathJax: `${}{}{}{}{}{}$`.

Comment: Why do you think what you wrote is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. $\log_2{8}$ can be thought of as what integer $x$ will make $2^x = 8$ a true statement. The (only) solution to that statement is $x = 3$. Similarly, $\log_3{27}$ can be thought of as what integer $y$ will make $3^y = 27$ true. The (only) answer would be $y = 3$.

Thus, $$\log_2{8} + \log_3{27} = 3 + 3 = 6$$ as what you would expect.

Answer (score -4):

Correct Answer:

$\log_2 8 + \log_3 27$

Log rule for different bases:
$\log_b a = \dfrac {\log a}{\log b}$

So

> $\log_2 8 + \log_3 27$
>
> $\dfrac {\log 8}{\log 2} + \dfrac {\log 27}{\log 3}$  (cancel the logs)
>
> $\dfrac 8 2 + \dfrac {27} 3$
>
> $ 4 + 9 = 13$

Comment: Cancel the logs?

Comment: @nyz It's an advanced technique for lvl $50$ mathematicians

Comment: @Some Guy I see